# Call controller from another module meanjs by angular modal service

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, mean, meanjs

> Blockquote

I created 2 crud module: customers and bookings. In module bookings, i call a modal from module customer with function:

```
function addCustomer(){
  var _modal_create = ModalService.showModal({
    templateUrl: 'modules/customers/client/views/form-customer.client.view.html',
    controller: 'CustomersController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      customerResolve: function(CustomersService){
        return new CustomersService();
      }
    },
  }).then(function(modal) {
      modal.element.modal();
  });
}
```

I added dependency into config of bookings module

```
angular
.module('bookings',['customers'])
.config(routeConfig);
```

Button call function addCustomer

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="vm.addCustomer()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Customer
</button>
```

I have error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: customerResolveProvider <- customerResolve <- CustomersController

Sorry my bad English.

Comment: Post the CustomersListController

Comment: @sachilaranawaka: oh sorry, it is CustomersController.

Comment: @sachilaranawaka i create moudule by code " yo meanjs:crud-module "